# How do I XOR in a specific spot in my integer?

Tags: c, binary, bit-shift, bitwise-xor

Could anybody please help me with this? With C I am trying to XOR(^) an int in a specific spot.

These are the steps:

Step 1: Grab and save the leftmost 4 bits before shifting

Step 2: Then I shift left by doing this on my code `num << 4`

Step 3: Then XOR in num from `17-20` with the leftmost 4 bits that were stored in step 1.

For Example:

Say I have an

```
unsigned int num = 7
```

this in binary would be

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111
```

Before shifting to the left by 4, I want to grab and save the leftmost 4 bits `0000`. Then I want to XOR from `17-20` of my num with the leftmost 4 bits that I saved.

This is for a hashing code I am creating. There is more to my code, but I am only sharing the part I am stuck and confused.

I have tried looking for other similar questions, but I don't understand what they are doing. If I could get an explanation that would be great.

Comment: It would help if you show all the inputs and the desired output.

Comment: Do you know how to **mask** the leftmost 4 bits? Do you know how to **shift** them right to a wanted location? You have a contradiction in the question though, you are asking to XOR 4 bits with 6.

Comment: `16-21` is 6 bits. How can you XOR that with only 4 bits?

Comment: This question is really unclear.

Comment: @WeatherVane I want the bits between 16 to 21 which would be 4 bits which would really only be 0000. I also want the leftmost 4 bits because I am writing a hashing code. Most of my code is written, but I got stuck in this part. Maybe the leftmost 4 bits don't make sense, but it will when my code is completed.

Comment: How about: `(num >> 28) << 16`? This assumes we right justify the 4 bit value within the 6 bit field. If we wanted left justify, it would be: `(num >> 28) << 18` If you wanted the leftmost _6_ bits: `(num >> 26) << 16`

Comment: Please add additional information by editing the question: one of more examples of all the actual input values and the output required.

Comment: Then you should have said "bits 17 to 20" and not what you did.

Comment: Ok, next part of the problem. You want to XOR bits 17-20 of `num` ...with what?

Answer (score 2):

OP is assuming an `unsigned` is 32 bit.  Let us be specific:

```
uint32_t num = 7;
```

> to grab the leftmost 4 bits of my num

```
uint32_t left4 = num >> (32-4);
```

> I just want to XOR from 16-21 of my `num`.  ... grab the leftmost 4 bits of my `num` then with those leftmost 4 bits then XOR in the specific location

Apparently [OP wants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790485/how-do-i-xor-in-a-specific-spot-in-my-integer/73790768#comment130298853_73790485) to XOR the 4 bits 17-20.

```
left4shifted = left4 << 17;
unint32_t result = num ^ left4shifted;
```

---

> but I am trying to create a hash code.

Best to post the whole algorithm.